# Is it necessary to write c code and generate a custom .so file when use tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, .so

I see some android example using tensorflow. For example, mnist and de demo app of tensorflow classifier, They all need to write some c code and generate a new .so file containing both c code written by developer and tensorflow library so.

Is it necessary to write c code and generate a custom .so file when implement a complicate deep learning task ?

And how can I build my own c code together with tensorflow library .so file to generate a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to accomplish almost any inference task (i.e. non-training) using the Java API and TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java similarily to the examples in the Android demo. You can use the prebuilt Android TF binaries in almost all cases unless you need to add new custom ops.